# Oculus Rift Linux example on virtualBox running on Mac

Tags: opengl, virtualbox, oculus

I use VirtualBox installed with Ubuntu 14.04 running on Mac OSX 10.10
When I download the latest Oculus SDK for Linux form the official website, I could successfully build it. 
But when I try to run it, the following message showed up

```
libGL error: failed to authenticate magic 3
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
RenderDevice::CreateTexture glGetError result: 1280
RenderDevice::CreateTexture glGetError result: 1280
RenderDevice::CreateTexture glGetError result: 1280
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadDrawable
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (X_GLXGetDrawableAttributes)
  Serial number of failed request:  2878
  Current serial number in output stream:  2878
```

Comment: You're generally not going to get hardware accelerated 3D when running a virtual machine and the Oculus Rift absolutely needs a dedicated hardware implementation of GL. I'd suggest adding the output of `glxinfo` to your question for completeness. There is a native OS X SDK (v 0.4.x) for Oculus, you should really use that or use Bootcamp to boot directly into Linux so that the Linux SDK for 0.4.3 will work.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Well I'd wait for the 0.4.4 SDK. Developers' experiences with the 0.4.3 SDK were rather, err, mixed. Definitely needs some more time to get mature.